# SQL return rows on or after an specific date

Tags: sql, date, where-clause

I am trying to export a list of member details that have an expiry date after 2019

```
|name  |expiry    |
|------|----------|
|arthur|2010-01-01|
|ben   |2018-05-17|
|craig |2005-12-30|
|dean  |2021-09-02|
```

so I am just after

```
|name  |expiry    |
|------|----------|
|dean  |2021-09-02|
```

I thought I could simply use the date in a WHERE clause

```
SELECT name, expiry
FROM table
WHERE expiry < GETDATE()
AND expiry >= '2019-01-01'
```

However, it still returns the other entries and not sure why

Comment: What database engine you are using? And what is datatype of expiry column?

Comment: 2018-05-17 is before 2019, not after 2019

Comment: `'2018-05-17'` is earlier than `'2019-01-01'` ... why would you expect the former date in your output?

Comment: sorry, typo. expiry is a date datatype

Comment: What are the result when you tried the code?

Comment: I think my mistake was using two separate conditions for the expiry date and should have used BETWEEN

Comment: [Edit] the question and provide a [example], i.e. the `CREATE` statements of the tables and/or other objects involved (paste the **text**, don't use images, don't link to external sites, make sure the statements are complete and compile, don't post just mere snippets), `INSERT` statements for sample data (dito) and the desired result with that sample data as ASCII or markdown table (see ["How can I create a table in a post?"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277716/how-can-i-create-a-table-in-a-post)). And tag the DBMS you're using and its version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you are using SQL Server:

```sql
SELECT name, expiry
FROM tmp
WHERE expiry < GETDATE()
AND expiry >= CONVERT(DATE, '2019-01-01', 102)
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=3c8e21a5b3822d416693d2131da61c6e)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The query should work the way you intend it to do. Probably the issue is caused by the expiry column not being of type Date for some reason. This could lead to unwanted behavior.